# What makes integration a 'global' operation, and how does this explain why it is harder than differentiation?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

Integration is often said to be a global operation. I suppose that this refers to the fact that the integral
$$
\int_{a}^{b} f(x) \, dx
$$
depends on the value of $f(x)$ on an entire interval $[a,b]$. This is in contrast to the derivative, which simply depends on behaviour of a function around a given point.

However, in practice to compute the above integral I would simply find an antiderivative of $f$ and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus. And since antidifferentiation seems as local as differentiation, I don't understand how this explains why the mechanical process of integration (both indefinite and definite) is so much harder than differentiation.

---

For a reference, Terry Tao makes this statement in the following Math Overflow post: '[Why is differentiation mechanics and integration art?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/66377/why-is-differentiating-mechanics-and-integration-art/66458#66458)'.

Comment: "I would simply find an antiderivative of $f$ and apply the fundamental theorem of calculus."  You can't always do that, and in many cases finding an antiderivative is much more difficult than verifying that said antiderivative is correct.

Comment: Inverse operations are not always of the same difficulty. Which is easier - plugging values into a polynomial, or finding its roots?

Comment: @DMcMor I hadn't thought about that, thanks. However, even the integration of elementary functions is much harder than the differentiation of elementary functions. And I can't think of an example of an elementary function which isn't continuous (and all continuous functions are integrable).

Comment: @Joe Elementary functions do have antiderivatives, but the antiderivatives are not necessarily elementary.  For example, $\exp(x^2)$ does not have an elementary antiderivative.  This, I think, is what DMcMor means by "You can't always do that".

Comment: @RobertIsrael Oh, I see. Thank you. Do you have any thoughts about this idea that integration is harder because it is global?

Comment: Compare the discrete version. Consider any function $f(n) $ given by a finite formula. It is easy to express $f(n) - f(n-1)$ as a finite formula, but usually difficult or impossible to express $f(1)+f(2)+\dots+f(n)$ as a finite formula.