# Why are "Most" integrals of elementary functions themselves not elementary functions?

Tags: calculus, integration, elementary-functions

I've been reading through Stewart's calculus, and it mentions how most elementary functions don't have elementary antiderivatives. I don't understand why the derivative of an elementary function is an elementary function, but the inverse operation(antiderivative) isn't. Below is a snippet of the text,

> For instance, the function
> $$f(x)=\sqrt{\frac{x^2-1}{x^3+2x-1}}+\ln(\cosh(x))-xe^{\sin(2x)}$$
> is an elementary function.
>
> If $f$ is an elementary function, then $f’$ is an elementary function but $\int f(x)dx$ need not be an elementary function. Consider $f(x)=e^{x^2}$. Since $f$ is continuous, its integral exists, $\ldots$

Comment: It's just how inverses tend to work in mathematics, intuitively speaking. The sum of two positive integers is a positive integer, but that need not apply to differences. The product of two positive integers is a positive integer, but that need not apply to quotients. The exponentiation of positive integers is a positive integer, but that need not apply to roots or logarithms. While it doesn't really "answer" the question, I think the gist that "inverses of nice things tend to be dirty" is a pattern you see a lot and worth noting here, and that this is an extension of that.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/20578) [questions](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3975533).

Comment: @PrincessEev I agree with the sentiment of your comment, but to apply it here would be to assume that differentiation is the "forward" operation, while taking the anti-derivative would be the (difficult) "backward" operation. Now, I do think that there is a fair case to be made for it being that way around (since anti-differentiation is only supposed to undo a differentiation), but I don't know if it's as obvious in that case as with the other examples of operations.

Comment: More related questions: [Q2194769](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2194769/) [Q2199236](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2199236/)

Comment: Is there any reason to expect the antiderivative of an elementary function to be elementary?